# Why does reversing the function not get me the original number?

Tags: python, math

I wanted to calculate the radius of a sphere from a given volume. As the volume was in ml, I converted it to mm^3. However, when I did a sanity check to put the radius back into the sphere formula, it gave me a number 1/4 of the original volume.

```
print minvol
mmminvol = minvol*1000
print mmminvol
rcubed = mmminvol/(4/3*ma.pi)
r0 = rcubed**1/3 #min radius
print r0
print 4/3*ma.pi*r0**3
```

Running the code gives me 
0.003 
3.0 
0.238732414638 
0.0569931657988

Not really sure what is going on...thank you in advance!

Comment: is this python2 or python3? I guess python2?

Comment: Make sure you aren't being bitten by integer division.  In some languages 4/3 = 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid such issues in future, use [pow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) function to calculate power.

```
import math as ma
minvol = 0.003
print(minvol)
mmminvol = minvol*1000
print(mmminvol)
rcubed = mmminvol/(4/3*ma.pi)
r0 = pow(rcubed,1/3) #min radius
print(r0)
print(4/3*ma.pi*r0**3)
```

The output is

```
0.003
3.0
0.8947002289396496
3.0000000000000004
```

Earlier you were doing.

```
print(rcubed)
#0.7161972439135291
print(rcubed**1/3)
#0.23873241463784303
```

Which means raise rcubed to power of 1 and divide by 3, hence your wierd behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

Missing parentheses:

Use this:

```
print minvol
mmminvol = minvol*1000
print mmminvol
rcubed = mmminvol/(4/3*ma.pi)
r0 = rcubed**(1/3) # this was changed
print r0
print 4/3*ma.pi*r0**3
```

Comment: if you use 30 = rcubed**1/3 instead this means you are saying rcubed^1 and that divided by 3 instead of rcubed^(1/3)

Comment: It all depends on the order of operations: first ** then * and / and then + and -

Comment: Oh god it was such a tiny little error but that fixed the problem, thank you!